# In coingecko, trying to get historical prices, but get the prices compared to every currencies

Tags: python, coingecko

When I use the `cg.get_coin_history_by_id('bitcoin', date='30-12-2017')` it seems to list the price compared to everything. I don't know how to make it just print one specific currency.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a .json it's a python dictionary. You can get the prices with the keys. For example if you want the price in US Dollars (USD):

```
>>> history = cg.get_coin_history_by_id(id='bitcoin', date="30-12-2017")
>>> price = history["market_data"]["current_price"]["usd"]
>>> price
```

output:

```
13620.3618741461
```

Answer (score 0):

`cg.get_coin_history_by_id` returns more than just price, it returns market cap, volume, etc... It isn't comparing the price to anything, it's just returning the data in multiple different currencies.

If you want to access the price for a specific currency just reference it using the keys you see in the response. For example, to get the price of bitcoin on that day in Australian dollars, you would do it like this:

```
api_resp = cg.get_coin_history_by_id('bitcoin', date='30-12-2017')
price_in_aud = api_resp['market_data']['current_price']['aud']
print(price_in_aud)

Output:
17446.3215245937
```

The structure of the json looks like this:

```
{
    "id":"bitcoin",
    "symbol":"btc",
    "name":"Bitcoin",
    "localization":{
       "en":"Bitcoin",
       .
       .
       .
    },
    "image":{
       "thumb":"https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/thumb/bitcoin.png?1547033579",
       ...
    },
    "market_data":{
       "current_price":{
          "aud":17446.3215245937,
          ...
       },
       "market_cap":{
          "aud":292616246981.057,
          ...
       },
       "total_volume":{
          "aud":4611856472.88116,
          ...
       }
    },
    "community_data":{
       "facebook_likes":"None",
       "twitter_followers":603664,
       ...
    },
    "developer_data":{
       "forks":13660,
       ...
       "code_additions_deletions_4_weeks":{
          "additions":"None",
          "deletions":"None"
       },
       "commit_count_4_weeks":147
    },
    "public_interest_stats":{
       "alexa_rank":2912,
       "bing_matches":"None"
    }
 }
```

source: [pycoingecko](https://pypi.org/project/pycoingecko/)